# Define two dependencies in a Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, openwrt

I would like to set my package to be dependent on 2 Config flags as follows:

```
1. TARGET_foo - Package require this flag to be set to 'y'

2. @!CONFIG_foo - Package require this flag to be set to 'n'
```

I tried to add the following line in my Makefile:

```
define Package/$(PKG_NAME)
    DEPENDS:=@TARGET_foo @!CONFIG_foo
endef
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seems to work.

Can any of you suggest a better solution (or at least a working one :-))

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is a syntax problem.

When setting a flag in config file, it is set as CONFIG_*******_yyyyy_xxxx etc. So the actual flag name is foo and not Config_foo

So, the following rule will work:

```
define Package/$(PKG_NAME)
    DEPENDS:=@TARGET_foo @!foo
endef
```